# Unable to scrape all rows of a table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried scraping the table rows from the website https://google.com/covid19-map/?hl=en to get the data on corona virus spread. But it only returns a few rows, in my case 15. I am unable to scrape all rows. The table isn't fully visible on the website, one needs to scroll to see the contents of the table. Please help.

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


URL = "https://google.com/covid19-map/?hl=en"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 

all_rows = soup.findAll('tr', attrs = {'class':'A5V3jc'})

for i in range(len(all_rows)):

    # Getting image link
    img_link = all_rows[i].find('img')
    if img_link != None:
        print(img_link['src'])

    # Getting name field
    name = all_rows[i].find('span')
    if(name != None):
        print(name.text, end ="\t")

    # getting remaining data
    remaining_entries = all_rows[i].findAll('td', attrs = {'class':'uMsnNd HAChlc'})

    for j in remaining_entries:
        if(j != None):
            print(j.text, end="\t\t\t")
    print("\n\n")
```

Comment: Try loading your page in your browser with java script disabled, you will see it only lists a handful in the table up to Austria, The site then uses a javascript event to go and retrieve the rest of the data and populate the table more. BS wont fire a JS event so you will only see the same data as if you loaded the page in your browser with java script disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com/covid19-map/?hl=en")
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1]

df.to_csv("Data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output: [view online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/e68d40bbe0e8ccc59daa5c05c55eab0a/Data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please help me get the links to the images of flags which is present in the src attribute of <img> tag ?

Comment: @TanishqVyas you've receive an answer according to your asked question. if you've another question, you've to open new question.

Comment: The following method doesn't work anymore. Even this returns a few but not all the rows of the table. I request you to please update your answer. It would be really helpful.

Comment: Well, I’ve taken time before to write for you that code and it was works as expected ! Now you’ve just un-accepted the answer and requested the code to be updated ! Do you really think that is logical ? You was can open a separate question and stating that the site is updated and the code is not works but by just un accept the solution which was works in the time which you received ! That’s really confuse

Comment: @TanishqVyas users here answer questions in their own free time and for free - they're not expected or obliged to keep answers up to date when things change - which is especially applicable to things like web scraping all the time. It seems this answer did work previously so if it doesn't now - that's not a fault of the person who answered. If another solution is required then it's best to ask another question perhaps linking to this one for reference and include your current results vs expected results and specific details regarding the difficulties you're now having.